# Loop takes too long to execute (looping through 365 days a year)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of manpower (40 people). I need to loop through a year (365 days) for each person to extract data for each day. But this takes too much time. Is there any suggestion to improve speed or a different method?

```
for (int man=0;man<40;man++)
{
    for (DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;date<DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);date=date.AddDays(1))
    {
        //do stuff
    }

}
```

EDIT: Stuff involves extracting data from a database where i get Projects each person is involved in, and start and end dates of the projects per person. (Each person has his own table and there is a master table with a list of all men). I have a datagridview, in which I show 40 men in the vertical axis. 365 days in the horizontal. Depending on the no. of projects, each person is involved in, I need to colourcode the corresponding cell.

EDIT 2:
        //A is a class that connects to a database, forwards a query and returns the result

```
 void colourchanger()
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < i; m++)//i=40
        {
            int copy = m;                             
            List<string>[] list = new List<string>[5];
            int number = A.Countproj(abc);//return no. of projects under man
            list = A.manprojselect(abc);//returns project details
            thread[copy] = new Thread(() => threader(copy,2*copy,list,number));
            thread[copy].Start();
        }
    }

void threader(int p, int x,List<string>[] list,int numberer)
    {
        DateTime labeldate;
        DataGridViewCellStyle AL = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        AL.BackColor = Color.Brown;//AL
        DataGridViewCellStyle NS = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        NS.BackColor = Color.Aqua;//NS 
        DataGridViewCellStyle training = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        training.BackColor = Color.Maroon;//training
        DataGridViewCellStyle one = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        one.BackColor = Color.Green;//one project
        DataGridViewCellStyle overseas = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        overseas.BackColor = Color.Blue;//overseas
        DataGridViewCellStyle two = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        two.BackColor = Color.Yellow;//2 projects
        DataGridViewCellStyle three = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        three.BackColor = Color.Red;//3 projects
        DataGridViewCellStyle unfeasible = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        unfeasible.BackColor = Color.Black;//self explanatory
        DataGridViewCellStyle none = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        none.BackColor = Color.Gray;//self explanatory


        string[] projname;
        string[] country;   
        string[] start; 
        string[] end;   
        string temp;    
        DateTime startdate;
        DateTime enddate;
            int[] track = new int[366];
            string[] projnames = new string[366];

                for (int y = 0; y < 366; y++)
                {
                    projname = list[0].ToArray();
                    country = list[2].ToArray();
                    start = list[3].ToArray();
                    end = list[4].ToArray();
                    temp = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText;
                    temp = temp[0].ToString() + temp[1].ToString() + temp[2].ToString() + temp[3].ToString() + temp[4].ToString() + temp[5].ToString() + temp[6].ToString() + temp[7].ToString() + temp[8].ToString() + temp[9].ToString();
                    labeldate = DateTime.ParseExact(temp,
                                           "dd-MM-yyyy",
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    for (int l = 0; l < numberer; l++)
                    {
                        startdate = DateTime.ParseExact(start[l],
                                           "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                        enddate = DateTime.ParseExact(end[l],
                                           "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                        int r1 = DateTime.Compare(startdate, labeldate);
                        int r2 = DateTime.Compare(labeldate, enddate);
                        if (r1 <= 0 && r2 <= 0)
                        {
                            track[y]++;
                            projnames[y] = projnames[y] + ", " + projname[l];
                            if (String.Compare(country[l], "Singapore ") != 0)
                            {
                                track[y] = 10;
                                projnames[y] = " " + projname[l];
                            }

                            if (String.Compare(projname[l], "ANNUAL LEAVE") == 0)
                            {
                                track[y] = 20;
                                projnames[y] = " " + projname[l];
                            }

                            if (String.Compare(projname[l], "NATIONAL SERVICE") == 0)
                            {
                                track[y] = 30;
                                projnames[y] = " " + projname[l];
                            }

                            if (String.Compare(projname[l], "TRAINING") == 0)
                            {
                                track[y] = 40;
                                projnames[y] = " " + projname[l];
                            }


                        }


                    }
                }

                for (int y = 0; y < 366; y++)
                {
                    if (track[y] == 0)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Style = none;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText + projnames[y];
                    }
                    if (track[y] == 1)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Style = one;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText + projnames[y];
                    }
                    if (track[y] == 2)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Style = two;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText + projnames[y];
                    }
                    if (track[y] == 3)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Style = three;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText + projnames[y];
                    }
                    if (track[y] == 10)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Style = overseas;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText + projnames[y];
                    }
                    if (track[y] == 20)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Style = AL;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText + projnames[y];
                    }
                    if (track[y] == 30)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Style = NS;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText + projnames[y];
                    }
                    if (track[y] == 40)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Style = training;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText + projnames[y];
                    }
                    if (track[y] > 3 && (track[y] != 10 && track[y] != 20 && track[y] != 30 && track[y] != 40))
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Style = unfeasible;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].ToolTipText + projnames[y];
                    }
                }
    }
```

DB used: SQL CE

EDIT 3: Manprojselect() posted

```
public List<string>[] manprojselect(string manpowername)
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM "+ manpowername;

            //Create a list to store the result
            List<string>[] list = new List<string>[5];

            list[0] = new List<string>();
            list[1] = new List<string>();
            list[2] = new List<string>();
            list[3] = new List<string>();
            list[4] = new List<string>();
            //Open connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //Create Command
                SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, connection);
                //Create a data reader and Execute the command
                SqlCeDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                //Read the data and store them in the list
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    list[0].Add(dataReader["Name"] + "");
                    list[1].Add((dataReader["Allotment_number"]).ToString() + "");
                    list[2].Add(dataReader["Country"] + "");
                    list[3].Add(dataReader["Start_date"] + "");
                    list[4].Add(dataReader["End_date"] + "");

                }
                //close Data Reader
                dataReader.Close();
                //close Connection
                this.CloseConnection();
                //return list to be displayed
                return list;
            }
            else
            {
                return list;
            }

        }
```

Comment: What "stuff" are you doing?

Comment: You could try inverting the loops, so you execute the date loop once, and the man loop 365 times. A loop over `int` should be slightly faster than over `DateTime`. Probably not even noticeable though..

Comment: Would be worth pulling your date loop start/end values out into variables (instead of creating new slightly different objects each time)

Comment: How can you know that is the loop that is slow, and not the "stuff"? You have 365*40 interactions, or 14600 loops, it is nothing for a computer... review your "stuff"

Comment: Right, there's probably a faster way to extract the data. I imagine you're currently performing at least 40*365 separate queries. We need more information about what you're doing inside the loop - that's where the problem is.

Comment: In light of your edit, therein lies the issue.  You are doing data access operations every single time through the loop.  Why not return your entire data set once, then loop over the results?

Comment: What version of the .NET Framework are you using? If it's .NET 4, please add that as a tag to your post... it will help others assist you more accurately.

Comment: .NET 4 Client Profile

Comment: You wish to buy 14000 pounds of cheese. So you go to the store, buy a pound of cheese, drive it home, go back to the store, buy a pound of cheese, drive it home... and do that 14000 times. Your conclusion is that this is taking so long because the checkout girl is so slow. Perhaps the problem is that you're driving the cheese around a pound at a time instead of a ton at a time.

Comment: @EricLippert, Understood. Thanks a tonne. While I haven't solved this problem, there was a similar problem elsewhere that I was able to solve. Thanks for the clever quip :). It hit home.

Comment: @EricLippert Hilarious :).  I love it! Excellent analogy

Comment: @EricLippert Love it. BTW - have any extra cheese you wanna sell?  ;)

Comment: @Geek: I made mozzerella from scratch the first time a couple days ago; turns out it is really easy. But I don't think I can make it in quantities large enough to be worth selling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to do 365*40 separate queries to the database. Typically, you want more of this to be evaluated server side.

To answer your direct question: yes, you can make the code go faster. This will not, however, solve your problem.

You can store the current date to a local variable and then use it instead of doing all those calls to DateTime.Now, which will check the system time each time.

```
var now=DateTime.Now;
var yearFromNow = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
```

... and then use these new variables in your loop.

You can also store all the dates in a list, reducing the number of calculations needed inside the loop:

```
var dates = Enumerable.Range(0,365).Select(n=>now.AddDays(n)).ToList();
```

Then you can access this list in the loop:

```
for (int man=0;man<40;man++)
{
    foreach (var dt in dates)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

... but this is not where your main performance problem is. Instead, you should post the **//do stuff**  body here, and possibly the type of db access you are using (LINQ2Sql,EF etc) so we can see if the whole thing can be optimized for *significant* gain.

The connection should not be re-opened for each loop pass.

Comment: The code that will give significant performance benefit is still hidden inside A.manprojselect(). What Db access technology are you using? Can you replace the expression "A.Countproj(abc);" with "list.Count();" after the call to A.manprojselect()? Is it possible to move A.manprojselect() inside the threader method?

Comment: I have posted Manprojselect as well. Thanks for taking your time to look into the problem.

Comment: Since CE does not allow multiple statements to be run in batches, assuming you need all the data and assuming that you have no way of skipping manpower units that have no data, there is little way around the need for 40 roundtrips if their respective data are found in 40 different tables. However, in your original code, you are using the variable "abc" when invoking Manprojselect. You are not using the loop variable. Can you explain the variable "abc"?

Comment: Did you get any performance benefit from using list.Count(); as suggested in my first comment? It saves you a roundtrip per manpower unit.

Comment: Yes, it did save me about 35% time. I have another question, is it possible that I can get the result from all the tables and the corresponding row count of each table with a single query.

Comment: I have a master list of manpower, in which manpower is listed as 'Bob Marley' or 'Eric Cantona'. But their corresponding table names are stored as 'Bob_Marley' and 'Eric_Cantona'.

Comment: However, there are cases where I get the error "Index was outside the bounds of the array." pointing at the parse statement.

Comment: There is a lot of stuff going on in your code, which you may seek to optimize. I think that you should do a test run commenting out all your code except the part that runs "Select * from <table>" and run it against the 40 different tables, and iterate the result through the datareader. If this is still too slow, you need to change the database to save number of roundtrips or rework your caching strategy.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. It was exactly as you said. Instead of opening the connection, executing the query and closing the connection for each of the 40 loops, I opened the connection, did 40 queries and then closed the connection. I achieved an improvement in performance from 14 seconds to only 2 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

It only loops 365*40 times, and it's a simple check. All your slowdown beyond that is being caused by `//do stuff`.

I'd add that this is actually a common problem - the length of time it takes to `//do stuff` is then multiplied by 365*40 (assuming stuff is takes a consistent amount of time over people and days).

Answer (score 3):

Try to extract data from database as a single bulk query or at least single query per person.

Analyze your data in code and even with unoptimized code it will work much faster than query for each cell.

Comment: Hey! Thanks, I did what you said and it totally worked!

Answer (score 2):

As stated, `//do stuff` is the culprit.

Without any more information, I can only suggest you try to use the `Parallel.For` method and make use of more threads (useful if you have more than one logical CPU core available).

Just remember that this will require you to take `lock` into consideration, as concurrent access to shared variables might cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun. How could I optimize that loop? I have tried with this

```
void Main()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    int max = DateTime.Today.AddYears(1).Subtract(DateTime.Today).Days;
    for (int man=0;man<40;man++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= max; x++)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();
    for (int man=0;man<40;man++)
    {
        for (DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;date<DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);date=date.AddDays(1))
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

}
```

First loop calculates the length in days of a year and then loops with an integer, the second one is the OP.
**The first loop is an astounding 19 milliseconds faster.**
Well, enough fun, back to work and try to optimize that **do stuff**

Comment: In the first loop you do not have a value for the date, why it is incomplete? Also, 19ms difference does not mean anything to us without second loop result.

Comment: @Dusan Do not take it seriously, it is not intended as a 'solution' but just to show that the problem is really elsewhere

Comment: Yes, OK, I was just wondering if I was missing something...
Anyway, how long does it take in ms for second loop?